# Ubuntu on MS Azure - how to setup nginx

Tags: nginx, azure

I created new VM with Ubuntu 14.04 and I'd like to setup nginx on it.

I installed nginx via putty ssh connection:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo ufw allow 80
```

However, when I go to server IP in the browser request is timing out.
I expected to see an nginx 404 error (I didn't modify nginx config).

Can anybody point me in right direction and tell what I should do to make nginx available by entering server IP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you allow port 80 in the firewall? (if not - `sudo ufw allow 80`) If you are accessing it on a different network than the server - did you set up port forwarding?

Comment: Also, try `ping -c 3 localhost` on the server.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju ping works correctly and I opened port 80 for http

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I found that vm has own firewall settings that has to be changed in VM Inbound Security Rules to allow access via port 80 (by default only ssh is allowed).